# $ A = $ { $ z \in \mathbb{C} : \vert z-1 \vert \leq \vert z-i \vert $ and $ \vert z-u \vert \leq 1 $ }

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $ u=2+2i $ and $ A = $ { $  z \in \mathbb{C} : \vert z-1 \vert \leq  \vert z-i \vert $ and $ \vert z-u \vert \leq 1  $ }

Find the module of $  z \in A $ so that the argument of $ z $ has a minimum value.

The correct answer should be $ \sqrt{7} $

Haven't encountered this type of exercises before. I guess the geometric representation of complex numbers will help.

Comment: Yes it will. Try drawing the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is the region below the line $y=x$ and inside or on the circle of radius $1$ centre $(2,2)$

Draw a tangent to the circle from the origin. You simply need the length of this tangent which is $\sqrt{7}$ by Pythagoras

Comment: The answer i get is $ \sqrt {5} $

Comment: Because i get the point $ (2,1) $ which is in A and makes the lowest angle

Comment: You need the point on the circle where the tangent from the origin touches the circle. This gives the minimum arg. You then have the line from $O$ to $(2,2)$ as the hypotenuse, with the tangent perpendicular to the radius $1$

Comment: Understood now, thanks

Comment: you are welcome